# React refs with components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have React form that has a Component used to render a drop down because the options are coming from an API. However, I can't access the ref for the embedded component. I'm putting together my first form and trying to understand the best way to approach this.

```
var ActivityForm = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var noteCategoryId = this.refs.note_category_id.getDOMNode().value.trim();
    var content = this.refs.content.getDOMNode().value.trim();

    if (!category || !content) {
      return;
    }

    // this.props.onCommentSubmit({author: author, text: text});

    this.refs.note_category_id.getDOMNode().value = '';
    this.refs.content.getDOMNode().value = '';
    return;
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="new-activity">
        <h3>New Activity</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <textarea ref='content' />
          <br />

          <label>Category</label>
          <ActivityFormCategoryDropdown /> # THE REF IN THIS COMPONENT ISN'T ACCESSIBLE
          <br />

          <input type="submit" value="Add Activity" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is preferred to treat the `ref` as a [callback attribute](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute) and no longer depend on the `refs` Object. If you do use the `refs` Object, avoid accessing `refs` of descendant components. You should treat `refs` as a private accessor and not part of a component's API. Treat only the methods exposed on a component instance as its public API.

For this case, I suggest grabbing the form from the submit event and traversing its child form elements as needed. Add `name` attributes since that's how form elements are identified in standard form submissions, and then you shouldn't need `refs` at all:

```
var ActivityForm = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = e.target;

    // Use the standard [`HTMLFormElement.elements`][1] collection
    //
    // [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements
    var content = form.elements['content'].value;

    // do more things with other named form elements
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="new-activity">
        <h3>New Activity</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <textarea name='content' />
          <br />

          <label>Category</label>
          <ActivityFormCategoryDropdown />
          <br />

          <input type="submit" value="Add Activity" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

*Update 2016-09-21: Revise suggestion to avoid the `refs` Object all together per guidance from the [`ref` String Attribute](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute) docs.*

Comment: Side note - This line: `var form = e.target.getDOMNode();` should be `var form = e.target;`

Comment: Negative points for using query selector, if the concern is refs use onChange.

Comment: @dirkdig Agreed about `querySelector`. This is an old answer, and I'm not sure why I thought that was a good idea.

Comment: @RossAllen , perhaps you can inform me then. When is it acceptable to use refs?

Comment: @dirkdig There's no simple answer for "when to use refs," but there is often a more maintainable way to reference components than via refs. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29504636/368697 is a good starting point to read and React's documentation on [Refs and the DOM](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) is worthwhile as well.

Comment: Another crucial point is to know when to use ref and when to avoid it. [This article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-ref-attribute-dom-node/) summarizes the use cases pretty well and showcases the ref attribute again.

Answer (score 20):

Composite components can have their own refs; you can reach in to them to access the refs further down the component hierarchy.

Example:

```html
<script src="http://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.11.2.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/jsx">
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var Parent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child ref="child" />
        <div><button onClick={this.handleClick}>Alert Text</button></div>
      </div>
    );
  },
  
  handleClick: function() {
    alert(this.refs.child.refs.textarea.getDOMNode().value);
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <textarea ref="textarea" />;
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<Parent />, document.getElementById("app"));
</script>
```

However, ssorallen is correct—you should try to avoid this if possible. Instead, you should either pass callbacks into children:

```html
<script src="http://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.11.2.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/jsx">
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var Parent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { text: "" };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child onChange={this.updateText} />
        <div><button onClick={this.handleClick}>Alert Text</button></div>
      </div>
    );
  },
  
  handleClick: function() {
    alert(this.state.text);
  },

  updateText: function(text) {
    this.setState({text: text});
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <textarea onChange={this.handleChange} />;
  },

  handleChange: function(evt) {
    this.props.onChange(evt.target.value);
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<Parent />, document.getElementById("app"));
</script>
```

or expose a public API in the child:

```html
<script src="http://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.11.2.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/jsx">
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var Parent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child ref="child" />
        <div><button onClick={this.handleClick}>Alert Text</button></div>
      </div>
    );
  },
  
  handleClick: function() {
    alert(this.refs.child.getText());
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <textarea />;
  },

  getText: function() {
    return this.getDOMNode().value;
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<Parent />, document.getElementById("app"));
</script>
```

or use some other data flow management (e.g. flux, events, etc).

Comment: The "managed" form element approach (your top example) is great albeit a larger upfront cost.

Comment: Hi, I want to know which way is better(first one I think) and why. Actually, why we want to avoid ref and use state. I see many posts on SO say that but I do not understand perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Now that the preferred value for the `ref` attribute is a callback (see the [`ref` Callback Attribute docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute)), it's misleading to show an example of accessing descendants' `refs`. That will likely break in a future version of React.