# Stateless function components cannot be given refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I try to access some refs in my component. But I have this error in the console.
`withRouter.js:44 Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs (See ref "pseudo" in FormInputText created by RegisterForm). Attempts to access this ref will fail.`

Here is my component:

```
class RegisterForm extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <form action="">
        <FormInputText ref="pseudo"  type="text" defaultValue="pseudo"/>
        <input type="button" onClick={()=>console.log(this.refs);} value="REGISTER"/>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Plus when I click on the button I got `Object {pseudo: null}`in the console. I would expect an object instead `null`.

I am not sure to understand why this is not working. Note that my react tree uses `mobx-react`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React stateless component this.refs..value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266411/react-stateless-component-this-refs-value)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Refs do not work with stateless components. It is explained in [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions)

> Because stateless functions don't have a backing instance, you can't attach a ref to a stateless function component.

Stateless components at the moment of writing actually have instances (they are wrapped into classes internally) but you can not access them because React team is going to make optimizations in the future. See https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4936#issuecomment-179909980

Comment: Yes I read that. So I am not sure what is a stateless, since I though using a class automatically create a state.

Comment: Plus, there is no state in the exemple. Is it ? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#a-complete-example

Comment: @DanielN the link also explains what stateless component is

Comment: @DanielN post `FormTextInput` code, please. I am pretty sure it is a function, not a class

Comment: Stateless functional components _can_ use callback refs in the render function to _internally_ access the DOM: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40795623/60647

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/) it has a function called [toClass](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#toclass).

> Takes a function component and wraps it in a class. This can be used as a fallback for libraries that need to add a ref to a component, like Relay.
>
> If the base component is already a class, it returns the given component.