# How can I attach to a stateless component's ref in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I am looking to create a stateless component who's `input` element can be validated by the parent component.

In my example below, I am running into a problem where the input `ref` is never being assigned to the parent's private `_emailAddress` property.

When `handleSubmit` is called, `this._emailAddress` is `undefined`. Is there something I'm missing, or is there a better way to do this?

```
interface FormTestState {
    errors: string;
}

class FormTest extends React.Component<void, FormTestState> {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({ errors: '' });
    }

    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <main role='main' className='about_us'>             
                <form onSubmit={this._handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                    <TextInput 
                        label='email'
                        inputName='txtInput'
                        ariaLabel='email'
                        validation={this.state.errors}
                        ref={r => this._emailAddress = r}
                    />

                    <button type='submit'>submit</button>
                </form>
            </main>
        );
    }

    private _emailAddress: HTMLInputElement;

    private _handleSubmit(event: Event): void {
        event.preventDefault();
        // this._emailAddress is undefined
        if (!Validators.isEmail(this._emailAddress.value)) {
            this.setState({ errors: 'Please enter an email address.' });
        } else {
            this.setState({ errors: 'All Good.' });
        }
    }
}

const TextInput = ({ label, inputName, ariaLabel, validation, ref }: { label: string; inputName: string; ariaLabel: string; validation?: string; ref: (ref: HTMLInputElement) => void }) => (
    <div>
        <label htmlFor='txt_register_first_name'>
            { label }
        </label>

        <input type='text' id={inputName} name={inputName} className='input ' aria-label={ariaLabel} ref={ref} />

        <div className='input_validation'>
            <span>{validation}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Add a `console.log` to your ref function to see if it is called

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React stateless component this.refs..value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266411/react-stateless-component-this-refs-value)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**EDIT: You now can with React Hooks. See the answer by Ante Gulin.**

You can't access React like methods (like `componentDidMount`, `componentWillReceiveProps`, etc) on stateless components, including `refs`. [Checkout this discussion on GH](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4936) for the full convo.

The idea of stateless is that there isn't an instance created for it (state). As such, you can't attach a `ref`, since there's no state to attach the ref to.

Your best bet would be to pass in a callback for when the component changes and then assign that text to the parent's state.

Or, you can forego the stateless component altogether and use an normal class component.

[From the docs...](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#the-ref-callback-attribute)

> You may not use the ref attribute on functional components because they don't have instances. You can, however, use the ref attribute inside the render function of a functional component.

```
function CustomTextInput(props) {
  // textInput must be declared here so the ref callback can refer to it
  let textInput = null;

  function handleClick() {
    textInput.focus();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={(input) => { textInput = input; }} />
      <input
        type="button"
        value="Focus the text input"
        onClick={handleClick}
      />
    </div>
  );  
}
```

Comment: @jasan are you wrapping your input in another component? if so, you'll need to expose the focus method on that class. If you're still having an issue inspect the value of textInput in when you're calling focus.

Comment: yes, I am using Field from redux-form.  I found the solution. cheers

Comment: Well you can still access the ref by passing the value from the ref to the parent, through a prop function, at the stateless component do

`ref={input => innerRef(input)}`

, on the parent use the prop you passed like you use ref normally;

`innerRef={input => this.customInputRef = input}`

Comment: this answer is obsolete since `v16.8.0`

Comment: how about when I wan't to use the textInput as soon as the page is loaded? how do I do the componentDidMount in functional component? I did use `` useEffect(x=>{
       //use here now textInput; but it is still null...
    },[])``

Answer (score 149):

You can use`useRef` hook which is available since `v16.7.0-alpha`.

**EDIT:** You're encouraged to use Hooks in production as of `16.8.0` release!

Hooks enable you to maintain state and handle side effects in functional components.

```
function TextInputWithFocusButton() {
  const inputEl = useRef(null);
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    // `current` points to the mounted text input element
    inputEl.current.focus();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input ref={inputEl} type="text" />
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Focus the input</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Read more in [Hooks API documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Comment: @Jafarrezaei Yes Hooks are in alpha at the moment but will most certainly be adopted.

Comment: @AnteGulin yes it will be adopted, but it's ALPHA. That means it's possibly unstable, with no guarantee that the current API will be what makes it to the final product. It exists purely for testing and feedback, NOT for production use.

Comment: It's out of alpha and even in react native now 7u7

Answer (score 7):

This is late but I found this solution much better.
Pay attention to how it uses **useRef** & how properties are available under **current** property.

```
function CustomTextInput(props) {
  // textInput must be declared here so the ref can refer to it
  const textInput = useRef(null);

  function handleClick() {
    textInput.current.focus();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={textInput} />
      <input
        type="button"
        value="Focus the text input"
        onClick={handleClick}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

For more reference check [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 2):

The value of your TextInput is nothing more than a state of your component. So instead of fetching the current value with a reference (bad idea in general, as far as I know) you could fetch the current state.

In a reduced version (without typing):

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = { _emailAddress: '' };

    this.updateEmailAddress = this.updateEmailAddress.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  updateEmailAddress(e) {
    this.setState({ _emailAddress: e.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    console.log(this.state._emailAddress);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          value={this.state._emailAddress}
          onChange={this.updateEmailAddress}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Assigning to state gets a little rough when forms get lengthy, which is why I was trying to solve this with the `ref`. I totally buy that what I'm trying to do is not possible here, but would you mind explaining, or referencing an article that explains why using `ref` is a bad idea in general?

Comment: Maybe you could compose your component in multiple levels? Try this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503213/use-state-or-refs-in-react-js-form-components

Comment: There's a word of caution here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs

Answer (score 1):

You can also get refs into functional components with a little plumbing

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

// Main functional, complex component
const Canvas = (props) => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

    // Canvas State
  const [canvasState, setCanvasState] = useState({
      stage: null,
      layer: null,
      context: null,
      canvas: null,
      image: null
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    canvasRef.current = canvasState;
    props.getRef(canvasRef);
  }, [canvasState]);


  // Initialize canvas
  useEffect(() => {
    setupCanvas();
  }, []);

  // ... I'm using this for a Konva canvas with external controls ...

  return (<div>...</div>);
}

// Toolbar which can do things to the canvas
const Toolbar = (props) => {
  console.log("Toolbar", props.canvasRef)

  // ...
}

// Parent which collects the ref from Canvas and passes to Toolbar
const CanvasView = (props) => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <Toolbar canvasRef={canvasRef} />
    <Canvas getRef={ ref => canvasRef.current = ref.current } />
}
```

Comment: where did you define getRef in Canvas component ?