# Using react-test-renderer with <Switch> causes "Stateless function components cannot be given refs" warning

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I am using react-test-renderer (16.0.0-beta.5) to perform snapshot testing on a custom React Native component. This component contains a Switch component, which causes this warning to be thrown during test execution:

> console.error node_modules\fbjs\lib\warning.js:36
>
> Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.
>
> Check the render method of `Switch`.
>          in Unknown (created by Switch)
>          in Switch

Minimal code to reproduce:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { Switch } from 'react-native';

test('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(
    <Switch />
  );
});
```

Some more detail: The issue is caused by the native RCTSwitch component used by Switch.render:

```
return (
  <RCTSwitch
    {...props}
    ref={(ref) => { this._rctSwitch = ref; }}
    onChange={this._onChange}
  />
);
```

As you can see this component is assigned a ref.
However, react-test-renderer uses the following code to check if a component is stateless:

```
if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && typeof value.render === 'function') {
  // Proceed under the assumption that this is a class instance
```

Because RCTSwitch doesn't have a render method, the warning is raised.
Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I added `jest.mock('Switch')` to the test and now it passes.

Note that doing this removes the Switch component from the snapshot, however since there is no reason to test a pure `react-native` component I think it's ok as long as all the functions that the Switch uses are tested separately.

Comment: If you want to keep the `Switch` component in the snapshot, you can do `jest.mock('Switch', () => 'Switch');`.

Comment: when i add this line it says "cannot find module 'Switch'".

Answer (score 0):

Stateless components don't support refs, create a stateful component.

For more detail see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266411/react-stateless-component-this-refs-value) answer

Comment: Switch is an component provided by react native, I'm afraid I cannot make that stateful. Besides, the warning only pops up in jest.