# How to ask for to do something in the child component from the parent component in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have one question about the react-way.

I have two components. For example: App & Browser.

- App is a general component. It loads inner modules and renders application tree-structure
- Browser is an inner-component of App. It shows some fetched data by its ID.

App-component doesn't matter about ID and data what currently rendered in Browser-component. App doesn't want to control browser-component's navigation. Browser is mostly independent.

But sometimes App wanna do one of it:

- Ask Browser-component for refresh (fetch data again + render it) active page
- Ask Browser-component to load particular ID

I don't understand how I can do it using react-way with props.

Some code for example:

```
class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return ... <Browser server={this.server}/> ...;
  }
}

class Browser extends Component {
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = { id: 'default' };
  }

  componentDidMound() { this.checkData(); }
  componentWillUpdate() { this.checkData(); }

  async checkData(){
      if(!this.state.data}{
          const data = await this.props.server.fetch(this.state.id);
          this.setState({ data });
      }
  }

  onChange(newId){
     this.setState({ data: null, id: newId });
  }

  render(){
    return <div>
        <Page data={this.state.data}/>
        <Navigation activeId={this.state.id} onChange={::this.onChange}/>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

I have some bad idea's. Example:

- I can set Browser to App by ref-attribute. And directly run needed methods
- I can use global variables
- I can provide empty {}-object into Browser-component. In initialization in browser-component set all needed methods into this object. Finally run it from App

I think all this variants isn't react-way. How I can do it right? 
I don't use redux in this project. Just react.

Comment: When do you want your `App` to trigger `Browser` for refresh? I mean the event of trigger?

Comment: When user is using NFC-tag or bluetooth tag.

Comment: whenever you do `setState()` inside `App` component it will run render method, so the `Browser`'s `componentWillUpdate` will be called, so this way it should call your `checkData` method

Comment: so basically you will need some state inside `App` in order to trigger UI updates

Comment: componentWillUpdate will be called. I can put there checkData(). But it won't do anything, because it looks at state.id instead props.id. State.id didn't change. App can't change child state. App can change only child props. But child is independent, therefore it can use either state.id or props.id, but not together.

Comment: so you want to send `id` to your `Browser` component?

Comment: Ok. Let them App has state { id: string }. It can provide it into Browser-component. But browser either use it instead self state.id, or use self state.id instead props.id. In first variant I need to make all logic in App. In second I can't trigger some methods in Browser. I'm in a trap :(

Comment: where do you get `id`? is it coming from fetch result?

Comment: Browser component is a navigation wrapper for Page component. It contains of all navigation logic code and renders only one Page component. It's a "container component". Page is presentation component. App is main application wrapper component.  

Browser initially loads default ids. And changes it when user click's in Page component.

Comment: It turns out that Browser component has 2 sources of ID. It's a main problem? It's a wrong situation?

Comment: What about `<Browser ref="browser" />`, then `this.refs['browser'].onChange( id )` from App? https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/64772/

Comment: pawel, yes! It's my 1st "dirty" decision from this topic :) Do you think that is an acceptable decision? I'm newbie in React and don't know how to do it right.

Comment: I think "ref"-mechanism is intended for custom DOM logic on browser real-DOM components. Hard animations, perfomance, etc. Also for DOM logic on non-react component.

Comment: @faiwer I guess this is the very case for `refs` being introduced in React

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React refs with components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941585/react-refs-with-components)

Comment: Simple example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pNZLXr

Answer (score 0):

I found one interesting decision. I can pass observer-method into child components. Example:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.subscribers = [];
    }

    subscribe = id => { this.subscribers.push(id); }

    anyMethod(){
        // ...
        for(let fn of this.subscribers)
            fn(newId);
        // ...
    }

    render(){
        return <div>...<Browser subscribe={this.subscribe} />...</div>
    }
}

class Browser extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        props.subscribe(id => { this.forceLoad(id); })
    }
}
```

It's like API for inner component gained from Parent component :)